# Automatising complex repetitive Tasks in Firefox in OSX

Tags: macos, automation, firefox-addon, applescript, automator

what would be the best way to automatise my complex work process:

**Problem:** I'm selling Designs online on various Platforms, so far: cafepress, redbubble and speadshirt. So every time I've finished designing I've to upload that design to each of these Websites, then choosing Keywords, a description and a title and save it. Every platform has further special tasks:

- cafepress requires to 1. click on "my designs" 2. click on "add designs" 3. Browse my files and add specific design 4. wait for upload then enter Title, Tags & Keywords then 5. click on save design 6. click on the recently added product 7. click on add products 8. select 1/6 cathegories 9. click on select all 10. click on create selected products 11. wait then redo step 7-11.
- redbubble requires to 1. click on add new work 2. browse to the work then upload 3. add a title, a description and keywords 4. Click on enable for the disabled products 5. For products "duvets", "Leggins" and "Scarves" click on edit -> Set size on 30% (slider) -> click on "repeat" -> click on apply changes 6. Select 2 Media tipes (checkbox) 7. Add it to a collection (checkbox) 8. click on "no" for mature content (checkbox) 8. click on save work.
- spreadshirt requires to 1. click on your account 2. click on "uppload design" 3. browse to your design 4. click on "confirm" 5. click on "describe" 6. add a title and keywords 7. click on "submit" 8. wait for submission then click on "create products" 9. click on a shirt 10. click on create 11. click on "design a new product" 12. repeat step 9 to 12 until you have ~8 Products 13. click on "my designs" 14. set a price 15. click on save 16. click on save again 17. click on "publish design" 18. choose a cathegory & a sub cathegory (dropdown) + add a description & accept the terms (checkbox) 19. click on submit.

As you see it is a real pain. Some times I spend more time uploading my designs than designing and I hate it! So I'm looking for a way to automatise it.

**Solution?:** would be a script (which language? which tool?) that does all those clicks and adds pre-defined text for Title, Description and Keywords at the respective place.

*How would you solve that issue? In applescript? with automator? with a firefox plugin?*

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you check out iMacros? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/